# Generate new data frame column based on content of current column using lamdas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple data frame with a columns labeled 'Vehicles', 'Red', 'Blue'.  The 'Vehicles' column has a list that includes items like 'Red Car', 'Blue truck' and so on.  I would like to populate the Red and Blue columns with a True or False dependant on the content of the 'Vehicle' column.  My poor attempt so far:

```
    df['Red'] = df.apply(lambda num: df['Vehicles'] == 'Red Truck'
      or df['Vehicles'] == 'Red Car')
```

ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index Count')

I am new to Python so struggling a bit with this.

Answer (score 2):

I am think this is more like a `get_dummies` problem

```
s=df.Vehicles.str.extract('(Red|Blue|Green)')[0].str.get_dummies()
df=pd.concat([df,s],axis=1)
df
    Vehicles  Blue  Green  Red
0  Red Truck     0      0    1
1   Blue Car     1      0    0
2    Red Car     0      0    1
3  Green Van     0      1    0
```

Comment: I like your answer, using the `extract` method. I think there is small error though in first line, the `[0]` needs to be gone: `df.Vehicles.str.extract('(Red|Blue|Green)').str.get_dummies()`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this if you're just looking for a target string is to use `.str.contains()`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Vehicles': ["Red Truck", "Blue Car", "Red Car", "Green Van"]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
    Vehicles
0  Red Truck
1   Blue Car
2    Red Car
3  Green Van

In [4]: df['Red'] = df['Vehicles'].str.contains('Red')

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
    Vehicles    Red
0  Red Truck   True
1   Blue Car  False
2    Red Car   True
3  Green Van  False
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time you see "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous," you've more than likely operated on a DataFrame, instead of a series. Try the following, instead, to get you through this block, and remember it:

```
df['Red'] = df['Vehicles'].apply(lambda num: num == 'Red Truck' or num == 'Red Car').astype(int)
```

Then probably forget it and try one of the other answers, as they'll probably be faster than using a lambda.

Notice that what I've done is operate on `df['Vehicles']`, and not `df`. Operating on `df` is going to pass the whole row to your lambda, which is not what you want. It's less a Python mistake than a Pandas mistake.

Comment: Really appreciate the insight - thank you for going to the trouble